# ThemeRoller for jQuery messes up the UI

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I am facing the following problem:
I'd like to use [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/?ver=1.0.1#importing) to apply custom themes to my views.
But as soon as I use them, the interface gets messed up, see the pictures below:

Without ThemeRoller:

[image: Without theme Roller]

With ThemeRoller:

[image: With ThemeRoller]

With ThemeRoller, refreshed:

[image: With ThemeRoller, refreshed]

Same goes for my navigation menu:
From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I have used the ThemeRoller as explained on their side. I am using the correct Version of ThemeRoller, matching my jQuery version 1.0.1 .
I have imported the file in the correct order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Themes/CustomTheme2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you miss any information, please leave a comment and I will provide them!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT_1:**

Instructions from ThemeRoller:

**To use your theme, add it to the head of your page before the jquery.mobile.structure file, like this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>jQuery Mobile page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script> 

</head>
```

Comment: As per their comments, you included this "jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" too ?

Comment: @Era I edited my post, from which source do you have this info?

Comment: as per my knowledge, js that creates/ apply styles to all the elements is rendering for twice. try to check that in console

Comment: Thanks a lot, excluding that file (along with the jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js ) worked. If you leave your comment as an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: Great. you did it .. (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, js that creates/ apply styles to all the elements is rendering for twice. try to check that in console.